# ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.2.0

Tags: python

I'm checking [this repo](https://github.com/adobe/Deep-Audio-Prior) and it says it requires torch==1.2.0 in its requirements.txt. So tried install them, but I got the error. The full error:

```
> pip install torch==1.2.0
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.2.0 (from versions: 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.10.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.2.0
```

I checked [this torch page on the PyPI website](https://pypi.org/project/torch/), it says it works if the python version is above 3.8, correct? I was on python 3.7.9 and able to run with torch>=1.8.0 on an another project, so changed virtualenv with python 3.10.0. Retying installing, but still I have the error, umm?

What's incorrect with this setup? Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show more context for the error message.

Comment: Actually that's the all message I get. `> pip install torch==1.2.0
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.2.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.2.0`

Comment: That's just a clarification. `pip install -r .\requirements.txt` has the same output. `> pip install -r .\requirements.txt
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.2.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.2.0`

Comment: Whats your CUDA version?

Comment: nvidia-smi says CUDA Version: 11.5. `> nvidia-smi
Sun Jan 30 15:57:39 2022
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 497.29       Driver Version: 497.29       CUDA Version: 11.5     |`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a different senario, in my case, I just downgraded the python version to 3.7.13 and torch installation was successful.
You may try to create a new conda environment with that version.
The torch installation command was `conda install pytorch==1.2.0 torchvision==0.4.0 cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch` (from [PyTorch site](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/))